# Multiple files making up Type Script project

Tags: javascript, typescript

Recently I have been working with TypeScript and everything has been fine and I really, really like it.. Makes JavaScript workable again! :)

we have tried to follow the same idea as we would behind any .net project e.g single file per class/interface

```
module Infrastructure {
    export interface IBaseViewModel {
        addOrRemoveClass(selector: string, className: string);
    }
}
```

the problem we have come across is this - all the dependent files are not being included? when it comes to being run.

If you look at this file which is the main entry point to our application, I get an undefined error on creating a new ViewModelBuilder

```
module Infrastructure {
    export class Fusion {
        constructor() {
            this.vmBuilder = new ViewModelBuilder();
            this.setApplicationDefaults();
            this.start();
        }

        private vmBuilder: IViewModelBuilder;

        private start() {
            this.vmBuilder.process();
        }

        private setApplicationDefaults() {
            $.pnotify.defaults.styling = "jqueryui";
            $.pnotify.defaults.history = false;
            $.pnotify.defaults.auto_display = false;
        }
    }
}
```

and at the top of the file we have

```
/// <reference path="../Typings/jquery.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="ViewModelBuilder/ViewModelBuilder.ts" />
/// <reference path="ViewModelBuilder/IViewModelBuilder.ts" />
```

also ViewModelBuilder

```
module Infrastructure {

    export class ViewModelBuilder { }
}
```

**So the question is this - What is the best way to go on? how can we get other class declarations to work?** our project is going to grow considerably we probably 100 view models which will represent each view (the project is a conversion from windows forms to web)

Any help would be fantastic as we really need to conquer this and move on! :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I wrote about [getting the right set up for TypeScript](http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201301/Blog/Getting-The-Right-Set-Up-For-TypeScript/) and one of the ideas in there will help you - I originally got the idea from Mark Rendle.

The idea is that create a file named `references.ts` and have all of your dependencies listed in there. A bit like this:

```
/// <reference path="modulea.ts" />
/// <reference path="moduleb.ts" />
/// <reference path="modulec.ts" />
/// <reference path="moduled.ts" />
/// <reference path="modulee.ts" />
```

You can then simply reference this file at the top of all your TypeScript files:

```
/// <reference path="references.ts" />
module ModuleA {
    export class MyClass {
        doSomething() {
            return 'Hello';
        }
        tester() {
            var x = new ModuleB.MyClass();
        }
    }
}
```

The `references.ts` file acts like the References folder you have for a .NET project.

The other recommendation, which works quite well with this set up, is to use the `--out` flag to compile a single JavaScript file, starting with `app.ts`. The TypeScript compiler walks all the dependencies and works out the correct order for all the generated JavaScript.

```
tsc --out final.js app.ts
```

This strategy will scale with your program much better than manually referencing specific files everywhere.

Comment: That seems like a good idea and would be ideal for a Release, how would this work for debugging and source maps?

Comment: I'll put my hands up here and say "I don't use source maps" - I'm pretty comfortable with the generated JavaScript so I debug it directly. I believe source maps are intended to work with the individual files rather than with `final.js`

Comment: Source maps should work with a `--out`-made file (I emphasize 'should' as this feature isn't fully stabilized yet).

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh Do you think this solution by Steve is acceptable? we are hoping to get this finalized soon. The Source maps are really important for us with debugging..

Comment: Yea, Steve's solution is generally what we try to use. I think it's the right way to go.

Comment: This was the approach I used to use, before 0.8.2, and I preferred it; but because I was splitting classes from the same module across multiple files ( see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14835586/understanding-internal-external-modules-and-import-require-typescript-0-8-2 ) I went back to the single-file method.

Comment: After trying this for a couple of days, it worked perfect! thank you all!

Comment: Note that if you use a build tool such as Gulp or Grunt, you can easily automate the creation of a 'references.ts' file. There's an excellent post from Dan Wahlin over here (http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-a-typescript-workflow-with-gulp). You can also check out the 'gen-ts-refs' task in my Gulp file: https://github.com/dsebastien/midnightLightV2/blob/master/gulpfile.js

Comment: If I do not use the compilation into one js-file, would I have to reference every compiled js-file separately in the html page?

Comment: @KaiHartmann you don't have to use TypeScript to merge the output into a single file... there are other (possibly even better) tools for combining and minifying JavaScript. Once your application gets really big, the single-file approach stops being viable and you need to use external modules with a module loader (ES 2015 has a module loader built in, but you can use RequireJS while you wait for browser support).

Answer (score 3):

If you come like me from a C++ / C background and miss the .h (or .hpp) files, I have a way. And you don't have to change compiler flags, or use ///, or anything. Just plain simple .ts files, import, export.

You create a folder, name it "models"

In this folder, you can create your models, say:

automobile.ts

```
export class Automobile {...}
```

car.ts

```
import { Automobile } from './automobile.ts';

export class Car extends Automobile {...}
```

ferrari.ts

```
import { Automobile } from './automobile.ts';
import { Car } from './car.ts';

export class Ferrari extends Car {...}
```

and then the magic - header files!

you create a file called models.ts (could be header.ts, whatever) in the same folder, where you just do

```
export { Automobile } from './automobile.ts';
export { Car } from './car.ts';    
export { Ferrari } from './ferrari.ts';
```

now, in your other files, to import all your models

```
import * as x from 'src/app/models/models';
```

and be happy using

```
let myCar: x.Car = new x.Car();
let myFerrari: x.Ferrari = new x.Ferrari();
```

Answer (score -3):

You have two options here, either commonjs, or AMD (asynchronous module loading).
Using commonjs, you will need to place a

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
```

for each separate javascript file in your project in your html page.
Obviously this can become very tedious, especially if you have hundreds of files in your project.
Alternatively, as Steve Fenton pointed out, you can use the --out parameter to compile various files into a single file, and then reference just this single file in your html page.

Using AMD is the third option - where you only need to include one script tag in your html page, and AMD takes care of references.
Have a look at my blog on how to get this working : http://blorkfish.wordpress.com/2012/10/23/typescript-organizing-your-code-with-amd-modules-and-require-js/