# Can you create Typescript packages? like c# dlls

Tags: reference, typescript

Is there any sort of notion of packaging typescript files currently?

One thing im finding a pain at the moment when trying to migrate a pure javascript project over to typescript is the references, in some cases where I have complex objects I am having to write several reference statements pulling files from all over the place.

Part of this is down to my project layout, as its a pretty big and modular one, so I have a system like this:

```
- modules
  |- module1
     |- models
     |- services
     |- controllers
  |- module2
     |- models
     |- services
     |- controllers
  |- core
     |- models
     |- services
        |- data
        |- validation
```

There is much more, but you get the point, now currently core is used by every module, but with javascript I just expect it to be loaded in at runtime, which will still need to happen, however as the typescript concerns are only really at compile time I was wondering if there was some notion of packaging all typescript files up into some typescript library or something, and then that could be referenced from projects rather than having module1 models referencing core models etc.

The problem currently revolves around the directory structures, as the namespaces work fine but if I move a file I need to go to every file which references that moved file and update it. Which is tiresome, whereas if there is some sort of package idea then I could just reference that once its output, so im no longer worrying about file systems and directories, im just worrying about a package and namespaces.

I think a lot of this is very similar to how C# works, you have a project which has references. Then every file within that project can use any of the classes within the references, so the code exposure is managed by references and namespaces.

I am thinking about having my build script just make a local references.ts file and just loop through every *.ts file in the relavant module and put them into one big file:

```
///<reference path="core/models/some-model.ts"/>
///<reference path="core/models/some-model-2.ts"/>
///<reference path="core/services/some-service.ts"/>
```

like shown above, then using this reference file in all typescript files which require core files, so this acts as a kind of project level reference, this may mean some files have references they dont need, but its compile time so I dont really care...

I dont want to go hand rolling my own solution to this problem if a good way already exists, Hope that makes sense...

== EDIT ==

I just wanted to post this up here as for my scenario has saved me TONS of time and has also reduced my reference guff by like 99%, this wont be applicable for people who don't have build scripts though.

Right now assuming you do have a build script I took the path of having a step in my script which went through every single file within a root level directory (module1, module2 etc in this case) and it would then output a local.references.ts into a references folder within that directory. Then I manually have written an external.references.ts which references external descriptors or other modules references wherever needed.

After this part was done when I am compiling my typescript I basically point it again at the root directories and tell it to compile them all (**/*.ts) into one big js file (i.e module1.js). Now because this will automatically include the local and external references, I dont need to put ANY reference declarations in the individual clases.

So this way providing the local and external reference files (local.reference.ts, external.reference.ts) are included within the bulk processing of the files you just have to worry about namespaces, making it pretty much the same as how C# would operate.

If however you do not have a build script which is able to do your local reference generation and compilation of typescript then the comment link given would be a good option.

Comment: I highly recommend the approach outlined here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15336006/1704166 . You can have one 'references.ts' per directory, or per logical set of directories.

Comment: Ah yes that is very similar to the approach im taking at the moment, although the build script is generating me my ``local.reference.ts`` files which is a big reference list of all files within that project.

Comment: After discovering the compilation process for multiple files will take ALL references into account for each file, not just the individual ones I have added an edit which can remove all individual references for each file if done right. AND will also make your builds more streamlined as your not dependant upon an IDE or NodeJS etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no formal process for packaging your source typescript files as a pre built library as you are describing.

There are a few different solutions currently used much like the one linked in the comments which will allow you to put all your references into central typescript files then just reference them from your individual scripts, or the approach you put forward where you do the same sort of approach but rather than manually writing it you get your build script to generate the references for you and get the compilation process to inject the references in rather than explicitly referencing them in each file.

As Typescript gets more mature there may be more formal ways of doing this, but for the moment just take whichever solution works best given your tooling and appraoch to developing with Typescript.