# Compile all TypeScript files into single TypeScript file

Tags: typescript

So I'm creating a TypeScript library and I can easily compile all generated JS files into a single file.  Is there a way to compile all .ts and .d.ts into a single .ts file?

It'd be nice to support a pure TypeScript implemented lib (for those who want the nice intellisense and to be able to debug the core TS  files) in addition to a JS supported version (lesser intellisense, can only debug generated files).

One solution would be to create a powershell script that concatenates all the files but I don't see a good way to do that dynamically (because of dependencies) without hard coding all of the file names in the correct order.

Comment: You can keep the dependencies in a different file which your "build" script uses instead of having it hardcoded. I use a json file for that, which makes it very easy to use with the python build script I have.

Answer (score 2):

You can compile your files into a .d.ts and .js

If you have multiple typescript files and run:

```
tsc --out mylib.js --declaration first.ts second.ts
```

You will get (mylib.js + mylib.d.ts) which you can then consume from typescript or javascript.

You can see an example here : https://github.com/basarat/ts-test/tree/master/tests/compileToSingle

Comment: I'm actually look for a way to create a single foo.ts file so that users can debug typescript source without having to look at the JavaScript implementation.  Having the definition files is definitely useful but doesn't let users debug there way into a project (at least not while looking at typescript).

Comment: @N.TaylorMullen I am looking for a way to do that as well. For this https://github.com/basarat/typescript-collections Having it in one file is ugly : https://github.com/basarat/typescript-collections/blob/gh-pages/collections.ts but seems to be the only option for now.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use command line arguments of compiler

`--out FILE` Concatenate and emit output to single file

### example

```
 tsc --out modules.js main.ts app.ts
```

The above answer is taken from this link

[TypeScript compiling as a single JS file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12926830/typescript-compiling-as-a-single-js-file)

Comment: I already have this implemented, I'm trying to compile all of my .ts files into a single .ts file., not a .js file

Comment: This doesn't merge the modules so its not that useful, throws the following error if you try `error TS6131: Cannot compile modules using option 'outFile' unless the '--module' flag is 'amd' or 'system'.` adding those flags just creates multiple files, unlike the solution by basarat (naming every file in the CLI)

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is a Typescript specific tool available which lets you basically munge all the files together, however if you have a build script just write a simple bit of code which locates all *.ts files within your project or desired scope, then just make a new file and keep appending these existing files to the new one. Then you will have a large `my-project.ts` which you can run through the `tsc.exe` with `--declaration` flag (or similar name) which would then output you a `my-project.d.ts` for it too.

If you are wanting to use it as a distributed library for others to use then you will have to package it in some way, be it one large .ts or some other mechanism... I asked a question along these lines before:

[Can you create Typescript packages? like c# dlls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15664032/can-you-create-typescript-packages-like-c-sharp-dlls)

Comment: What about dependencies?  AKA lets say A.ts depends on B.ts, isn't it important that B.ts is at the top of the combined file followed by A.ts?

Comment: Gave it a shot, and sadly order does matter when all files are concatenated into a single file.