# Compiling TypeScript project composed of many files/modules to single file

Tags: typescript

I'm writing a [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org) application, and requirements mandate that it be compiled to a single file; I don't want to lose out on defining modules, and to make the project easier to manage, I want to put them in multiple files. The common approach of:

```
import _option = require("Option.ts")
```

Doesn't work because it requires CommonJS or AMD, which I am unable to use. Is there a way to use multiple files and modules in a project, but still compile them all to a single file without use of CommonJS or AMD?

I attempted to use the `tsc` transpiler option `—out FILE` to generate a single file, but it chokes when you use the `export` keyword anywhere in any of your files.

Comment: You need "internal" modules.  ``export`` defines an "external" module.  Read up on the TypeScript docs to first find out the difference between the two.

Answer (score 3):

In order to use proper (external) modules and then output a single file, your best best is to combine an AMD builder like [r.js](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/) with AMD modules output from the TypeScript compiler. You compile to individual JavaScript files from TypeScript, and then r.js builds it into a single layer file.

Before you say this isn’t really what you want, you’re probably going to want to minify your code as well, right? In that case, the TypeScript compiler won’t do what you need, but r.js will. Since you need to have that extra build step anyway, use proper external modules and build it into a single file as part of your build process instead of doing what you’ve proposed in your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use the "`///<reference path="reference.ts"/>` at the top of your ts file" approach. This seems simple enough if you know about it; there is lots of stuff about AMD and CommonJS for including modules though that makes finding out about it difficult.

So, to elaborate on the solution, given three files, `main.ts`, `B.ts`, and `C.ts`, where `C.ts` uses classes/modules in `B.ts`, and `main.ts` uses both, this lets you do:

In `C.ts`:

```
///<reference path="B.ts"/>
module C {
  class Foo {}
}
```

In `main.ts`:

```
///<reference path="B.ts"/>
///<reference path="C.ts"/>

// Use modules directly
var a = new C.Foo();
```

Then from the command line, you use `tsc --out file.js main.ts`, which will transitively pull in all dependencies and combine them. *Note* that you must not have any root level `export` statements in your files or they will not be included in the file output; conversely, all defined modules/classes in the files are accessible without using the `export` keyword. If you were relying in the past on a file representing a module, you will now need to wrap that content in a `module X { /* original file code here */}` type declaration.

Another advantage to this approach, is that it lets IDEs like IntelliJ introspect all the types and give you autocompletion and error detection properly for each file.

If there are *lots* of files you wish to include all over the place, it might be worth using the ["single `references.ts` file" approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15335474/multiple-files-making-up-type-script-project), where you list out all references in one file and reference that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some build tools like [esbuild](https://esbuild.github.io/).

1. install esbuild with `npm init -y` and `npm i esbuild`.
2. In package.json add 2 commands:

```json
  "scripts": {
    "build": "esbuild  index.ts --platform=node --format=esm --bundle --outfile=index.mjs",
    "start": "node index.mjs"
  },
```

3. Run `npm run build` and `npm start`.

I am using node v16.14.0.